# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate do execute save methods, but don't execute insert/update statements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

**Issue**

The problem is that, at each build of the project with Maven, the build produces **randomly** a working jar or a broken one. Obviously there aren't any changes neither in code or configuration.

What I mean with broken?

- Broken Jar. The Job starts and ends correctly, without exceptions, without rollback of any kind, and with all save methods of CrudRepository executed just fine. The problem is that even if I see in the log the select statements to fetch the next value of the sequences for the inserts, the inserts are never logged. Checking the DB, the inserts are not only not logged, but actually they are all never executed. In fact, the corresponding tables remain empty! One more important detail is that the entities passed to the CrudRepository save methods have the IDs set. This is the case for all save/updates, and not only for some of them.
- Working JAR. Both select and insert statements are logged correctly and record are inserted in tables.

Usually, each 5/6 builds, 1 working JAR is generated, while 4/5 are broken. 
The broken and working jars are identical with binary comparison.

Once a JAR is compiled, if it is broken, each execution will be broken, regardless of how many times it is executed. Same goes for the working one.

**What I Already Tried**

1. Changing Spring/Hibernate versions
2. Compiling on different machines
3. Replacing CrudRepository with JpaRepository
4. Forcing commit with saveAndFlush (resulting in the generation of an exception)

**Configuration**

I have a Spring Batch Project, based on Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. The batch is executed by a sh file. As you can see in the configuration, for debug reasons, I have `hibernate.show_sql` parameter set to true.
The database is Oracle 11g.

POM:

```
    <properties>
         <spring-version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <hibernate-version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    .....
  </dependencies>
```

Hibernate Properties:

```
hibernate.synonyms=true
hibernate.allocationSize=1000
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updates=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
```

**Working Log:**

```
2019-06-27 10:42:03.558 [pool-3-thread-19] INFO  i.a.n.b.t.XXX (246) - Elaborazione TABLE1 con SEQU: 2071042
Hibernate: select SEQUENCE1.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into TABLE2 (........) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select column1, column2 ... from TABLE3  where condtion
2019-06-27 10:42:03.651 [pool-3-thread-19] INFO  i.a.n.b.s.i.BaseOrderServiceImpl (185) - Recuperato record dalla TABLE3 con ID : 2071042
```

**Broken Log:**

```
2019-06-27 10:42:03.558 [pool-3-thread-19] INFO  i.a.n.b.t.XXX (246) - Elaborazione TABLE1 con SEQU: 2071042
Hibernate: select SEQUENCE1.nextval from dual

INSERT MISSING HERE

Hibernate: select column1, column2 ... from TABLE3  where condtion
2019-06-27 10:42:03.651 [pool-3-thread-19] INFO  i.a.n.b.s.i.BaseOrderServiceImpl (185) - Recuperato record dalla TABLE3 con ID : 2071042
```

**Call for help:**

I am building my project multiple times each time I need to deploy it, for months. I'd like to solve this problem once and for all and I'd appreciate your help.

If you need snippet of codes ask me, but generally they are normal save with basic entities, with `@Transactional` notation working fine with working JAR.

Thank you.

**Update**

As suggested I tried to uniform spring and hibernate dependencies to the same version. The problem is still there.

Update pom

```
 <properties>
    <spring-version>5.0.12.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: R u using MySQL?

Comment: I forgot to provide this information: no, I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: Firstly, i would make all versions of dependencies be compatible with each other according to https://mvnrepository.com. For example 1) you have spring-data-jpa of version 2.1.5.RELEASE. Lets go to [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.5.RELEASE) and find that it depends on hibernate-core of version 5.2.17.Final. And you have 5.4.1.Final. 2) you have spring-orm of version 5.1.5.RELEASE and [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.1.5.RELEASE) it depends on hibernate-core of version 5.3.7.Final

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to fix versions dependencies and I'll update the post with the test results

Comment: Nothing, same error. I'm gonna update the questione with the updated pom

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the following steps:

- Versions revion suggested by @bdshadow.
- I had a @Configiguration class, with @EnableJpaRepositories, with *entityManagerFactoryRef* and *transactionManager* refering to bean defined in this class. The beans had the default qualifiers *entityManagerFactory* and *transactionManager*. I changed the qualifiers and added the notation @Primary to them.

These steps resolved the issue.